# OpenGL shader does not compile but gives no error message

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to write a function for loading and compiling a shader using OpenGl, but the shader refuses to compile while giving me an empty (or random) error log.

The following is my minimal example:

```
vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
std::string vertexSource = ShaderLoader::load("vertexShader.vert");
const char * vertexAdress = vertexSource.c_str();
glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexAdress, NULL );
int shaderCompiled = GL_FALSE;
char errorLog[512];
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shaderCompiled );
glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, nullptr, &errorLog[0]);
glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
```

Outputting `shaderCompiled` gives `0` and `errorLog` gives either an empty string or a few random characters.

The function `ShaderLoader::load` contains the following code:

```
std::string ShaderLoader::load(std::string source) {
    std::string shader;
    std::fstream readFile(source, std::ios::in);
    if (readFile.is_open()){
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << readFile.rdbuf();
        shader = buffer.str() + "\0";
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Couldn't load shader file: " + source);
    }
    return shader;
}
```

It seems to be working as expected. The shader source code is

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inVertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inNormal;

out vec3 FragmentPosition;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    FragmentPosition = vec3(inVertex);
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(transform))) * inNormal;
    gl_Position = transform * vec4( inVertex, 1 );
}
```

How can I populate `errorLog` with an actual error message, or even better, get the shader to compile.

Comment: It is a typo. You are using the 2 different variables `vertexShader` and `shader`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However, it, unfortunately, does the same thing after changing the variable name. I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry the issue is not reproducible. The code works fine. The shader code is correct and can be compiled successfully.

Comment: Do you check for `glError`? Because `shaderCompiled` is only altered when no error happens. You initialize it with false, thus it might simply not have been changed before you check it. As Rabbid76 already said: The shader compiles fine for me.

Comment: I must have made something strange in the rest of my code. Unfortunately, `glError` returns `GL_NO_ERROR`, so I'm still in the dark. Either way, thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 1):

First only use error logging if shaderCompiled is false so you don't get random strings,

```
  glGetShaderiv(VS, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shaderCompiled);
  if (!shaderCompiled)
  {
    //error
    GLchar InfoLog[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
```

Second, are you actually linking and using the shaders, the problem might not be with the compilation:

```
  // after compilation
  GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
  glDetachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
```